# how to get append my api key on URI given by british airways

Tags: html, angularjs, api, url, uri

This is the link of british airways developer site: https://developer.ba.com/ApiInfo

How to apply my key to the link and get information ?

**Format of a URI**

A resource is accessed using a URI in the following format:

```
https://api.ba.com/rest-v1/{resourceVersion}/{resourceName};{filters}
```

The API makes use of Matrix Parameters to filter resource requests. Matrix parameters are specified using name=value pairs separated by a semicolon e.g.

```
flights;departureLocation=LHR;startTime=06:00;endTime=11:00
```

would result in details of all today's flights departing from LHR between 6am and 11am local time.

I am confused on how to apply my api key on above information. Basically i need url where i can apply my key

I am doing angular js, API CALL:

```
$http({ url: URL, method: 'GET', headers: {
                    'Client-Key': 'MYkey'               
                }
            }).success(function (response) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply the key to the URL, it's applied in the request header;

If your key is 'ImADeveloper', you need to add the header;

```
Client-Key: ImADeveloper
```

...to the request.

You can see the API in action (including the API keys in use) [at this page](https://developer.ba.com/io-docs).

Comment: can you pleae provide me an example of using it , I am learning it newly/

Comment: @user2936008 If you could add the relevant part of your current non working code to the question and I'll see if I can suggest changes to what you have.

Comment: can you pleae provide me an example of using it , I am learning it newly . How can we set in the request header to get information.

Comment: sure I will do that and post in this question thanks Joachim Isaksson

Comment: $http({    url: URL, method: 'GET', headers: {
                        'Client-Key': 'IamADeveloper' }
                }).success(function (response) {} => I have used this , i am doing angular js experiment

Answer (score 0):

Example in C#

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  client.Headers.Set("Client-Key", "yourapikey");

  string response = client.DownloadString("https://api.ba.com/rest-v1/{resourceVersion}/{resourceName};{filters}");
}
```